# Value of the function at such points are finite or not

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is Theorem 1.3 in Stein’s *Real Analysis*.

> If $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^d$, then 
>   $$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\ x\in B}}\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy=f(x)~~~{\rm for~a.e.~}x\in \mathbb{R}^d.$$

I wonder if the values of $f$ at those points at which the equality above holds are finite. Or in other words, is the function finite pointwise everywhere at those points? I can give a easy counterexample but I’m not sure if this is the right way to think about it:

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $f(x_0)=\infty$. We also have
$$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\ x_0\in B}}\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy=\infty=f(x_0).$$

This gives a counterexample because in the field of real analysis if the limit is infinity we say the limit exists.

Does my counterexample make sense? If not, could you give me some ideas about my origin question? Thank you!

Comment: I presume it's supposed to be "for a. e. $x\in\Bbb R^d$".

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks! It was a typo, my fault.

Comment: What kind of sets is $B$ allowed to be? Any Lebesgue measurable set sounds too good to be true.

Comment: I would assume that the author defines $f:\Bbb R^d\to\Bbb R$, and therefore that all Lebesgue point must have finite limit. It is, on the other hand, it is possible to phrase integration for functions $f:\Bbb R^d\to [-\infty,\infty]$, in which case a function is integrable if and only if $\{\lvert f\rvert=\infty\}$ is a null set and $1_{\{\lvert f\rvert<\infty\}} f$ is integrable in the usual sense (with the convention $0\cdot\infty=0$). Therefore the result at hand does not quite see the difference. Specifically: [continues]

Comment: [continuation] I could make the argument that the function $\lvert x\rvert^{-1/2}$ on $\Bbb R$ stands for $g(x)=\begin{cases}\lvert x\rvert^{-1/2}&\text{if }x\ne0\\ 11&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$, in which case $0$ is not a Lebesgue point for $g$ because the limit is $\infty$. I could make the argument that it stands for $h(x)=\begin{cases}\lvert x\rvert^{-1/2}&\text{if }x\ne0\\ \infty&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$, in which case $0$ is a Lebesgue point and I have to deal with having infinities popping out. I could also insert the caveat that the limit in the definition of Lebesgue point is finite.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thanks for your nice comments. But don’t we say the limit exists if the limit is infinity?

Comment: @Benny Balls and cubes I understand, but what about a ball away from $x$ together with the singleton $x$? That is also a Lebesgue measurable set, but the result does not hold if we let the radius of the ball go to zero.

Comment: @Benny I guess is the standard phrasing in English would be that when the limit "is $\infty$", the limit doesn't exist. However, it's linguistics: if I want to say that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$ and $f(a)=\infty$, and I have a good reason to do so, it's not like the Party comes looking for me. The point is that no amount of discussion between us will give you a more satisfactory answer than you reading your copy of the book backwards until you find what the author means.

Comment: Dasherman is correct. This does not hold over all measurable sets $B$ containing $x$. For example, let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : t \mapsto t$ and $x = 0$, and consider the sets $B_n = (-1/n,1/n) \cup (1-1/n, 1+1/n)$. $0$ is in all of these $B_n$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} m(B_n) = 0$, but $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac1{m(B_n)}\int_{B_n} f(y)\,dy = \frac 12 \ne f(0)$$Likely the theorem is only referring to balls centered at $x$, though somewhat looser restrictions will also work.

Comment: On the question of whether the "limit exists" when it is $\infty$, that depends on where we are taking the limit. If we are taking limits in $\Bbb R$, then no, the limit does not exist, because $\infty \notin \Bbb R$. If we are taking limits in the extended reals, $\overline{\Bbb R} = \Bbb R \cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$, then yes, it exists because $\infty \in \overline{\Bbb R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f \in L^1(\Bbb R^d)$ and $f(x_0) = \infty$ are not enough to say
$$\lim_{\substack{m(B)\to 0\\ x_0\in B}}\dfrac{1}{m(B)}\int_B f(y)dy=\infty$$
even when the $B$ are limited to balls centered at $x_0$. For example $$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 &x \ne 0\\\infty & x = 0\end{cases}$$

To get the limit to be $\infty$, you need a function like $$f(x) =\begin{cases} \infty & x=0\\|x|^{-1/2}&0<|x| < 1\\0&|x|\ge 1\end{cases}$$

And that is also the answer to your question. Neither the function itself nor the limit needs to be finite at the points $x_0$ where the equation holds.